# An GPU could help to make this process quickly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cloud, gpu

I used an autoregressor to train a random forest regressor on electrical demand data every 5 minutes, but it took 16 hours to train.

```
forecaster = ForecasterAutoreg(
                regressor = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=123),
                lags = 2016
             )
```

For the training I am feeding it a total of 85675 data and for the test I am using 44136 data.

For reasons of time I cannot apply a gridsearch properly without it lasting several days.

My question is: Would the use of a GPU (virtual or physical) improve these execution times? Any recommendations to improve execution times? Is there any platform that offers GPUs for free? Colab and Kaggle no longer provide according to me.

It is worth mentioning that he tested it with data from daily intervals and the execution is done in a maximum of 1 minute. Right now I don't have any GPU.

Comment: Where does `ForecasterAutoreg` come from? I don't know it as part of scikit-learn, or am I wrong?

Comment: It comes from Skforecast, Here is the doc of https://skforecast.org/0.4.3/index.html

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html):

> n_jobsint, default=None 
>  The number of jobs to run in parallel.
> fit, predict, decision_path 
>  and apply are all parallelized over
> the trees. 
>  None means 1 unless in a joblib.parallel_backend
> context. -1 means 
>  using all processors. See Glossary for more
> details.

Same thing by the way for `GridSearchCV`!

So: Try

```py
forecaster = ForecasterAutoreg(
                regressor = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=123, n_jobs = -1),
                lags = 2016,
             )
```

This tries to parallelize the computation to all your available cores.

Comment: I completly forget about taht. I´m trying right now,  i comeback later to share the improve